# Files not getting converted to wav from mp3 using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, wav

Hi I am converting some audio files from .mp3 format to .wav. Some audio files are getting converted whereas some files are not getting converted.

The code I am using is:

```
sp.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', downloadPath2, '-ar', '8000', '-ac', '1',
  AUDIOPATH +'/'+ call + '-out.wav'], stdout=FNULL, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
```

Can anyone suggest why some files are not getting converted to .wav?

Comment: Why are they not getting converted? (What are the error messages?) Please add more details. Last, whatever your issue is, it is unlikely caused by FFmpeg.

Comment: Its not showing any error. Even I think the issue is with the audio file. But I am able to listen to the .mp3 version of that audio. Can anyone say what properties of an audio files needs to be checked in order to understand the problem eg.bitrate.

Comment: did you confirm you can play the mp3 which fail to convert ? possibly invalid mp3 ... also from a terminal issue ...  `ffprobe some-questionable-file.mp3`  to see if probe kicks up any dust

Comment: Assuming you're running Python, it doesn't show anything the way you have it because you're routing all the log message to nulldev (i.e., throwing them away). Remove `stdout` and `stderr` arguments and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the code and did find that there was a line of code:

sp.call(['rm', AUDIOPATH + call + '-out.wav'], stdout=FNULL, stderr=sp.STDOUT)

On commenting the above line the audio was converted for all audio files.But still I am yet to figure out why some audio files were converted whereas others were not.In case I come across the solution I will be posting it on this board.